# Override extends class exist variable with annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to know is there any way to extends a parent class and override its variable with adding an annotation? or if it can't, is there other workaround to achieve the same goals?

```
public class address {
  private Integer postalCode;
}

public class validateAddress extends address {
  @NotNull
  @Valid
  private Integer postalCode;
}
```

Comment: No, you can't override fields. If you want a workaround to achieve your goals, it'll help to explain what your goals are.

Comment: my goals is to separate two exact class but the different is first class is don't need to validate anything and the sec class need to validate **SOME** field because the sec class intended to be a request class for springboot and the first class is going to be the response. @shmosel

Comment: Why not make them separate classes?

Comment: because i just need to add annotation for some field and not all of them, creating whole new class with a little bit modify i think it's gonna be a redundant.

Comment: and the parent class has many internal function to process data, it's a little bit messy if i copy all of it to the new class.

Comment: How about creating an abstract base class for both and adding the variable fields to each subclass?

Comment: i was thinking that way too, but the parent class already implemented in so many places and that's mean i need to refactor it in all places. But if there aren't any other choices than this is going to be my last bet.

Comment: It shouldn't take much refactoring. No one has to know that `Address` extends `BaseAddress`.

Comment: Having two redundant classes, one simple pojo for data transfer (commonly called DTO), and one implementing the actual business logic, is quite common, you shouldn't be afraid of that. You will be happy to have two different classes when you will have to implement computed fields only for display, or when interfacing your app with external services, without be tied to your business class.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record I think all the suggestions in the comments are great. I am answering this since I saw no one mentioning this method.

Following are my assumptions based on your question and the code snippet:

1. The parent class is not supposed be modified.
2. The variable in the parent class is private as mentioned.

Based on the above, since the variable is declared private, it cannot be inherited by a subclass i.e. there will not be any copy of the variable accessible to the subclass's object. So there is no straight way of doing this.

A workaround I can think of is using the JAVA reflection API (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) to access and put validations on the private fields.

You can access the private field as:

```
Field privateField = <SuperClassName>.class.getDeclaredField("name");
privateField.setAccessible(true);
```

Now you can validate this.private field as you want. This is a very high level explanation, since I dont exactly know the actual requirement.